# Why am I not getting hot water from my heater?

Tags: water, water-heater

I have the water heater pilot on but I don't have any hot water flowing. I do have cold water running through the pipes. My water heater is in the garage and it's freezing temps. I had a heater on the pipes and it didn't in freeze.

What could be my problem?

Comment: I would check the water heater thermostat first.  That lets the heater know to turn on the main gas to heat the water.

Comment: Yup, double check the settings on the heater. Maybe somebody bumped it. Maybe somebody's messing with you. Maybe it's just _barely_ hot enough during the summer, and now that it's frigid outside, the water's cooling enough as it travels from the heater to the faucet that it's effectively cold by the time it gets there. Also, "I do have cold water running through the pipes" does this mean you're getting cold water when you turn on the hot, or that you get cold from the cold side?